# What does the "Mariabackup: garbage block" error mean?

Tags: mariadb

I'm attempting to use mariabackup to do a streaming backup of a remote mariadb instance (production database under load) to the local machine, using the command:

```
ssh root@dbserver 'mariabackup --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf \
--socket=/db/mysql/mysql.sock --user=root --backup --parallel=4 \
--stream=xbstream --tmpdir=/tmp/mysql-backup-tmp' | mbstream -x
```

However, during the process, the following error message appears:

```
180722 03:17:35 >> log scanned up to (178256886852267)
180722 03:17:36 >> log scanned up to (178256886852796)
180722 03:17:37 >> log scanned up to (178256886857155)
mariabackup: garbage block: 178256886865408,12
180722 03:17:38 >> log scanned up to (178256886865408)
180722 03:17:39 >> log scanned up to (178256886869872)
180722 03:17:40 >> log scanned up to (178256886893932)
```

Is this "garbage block" error a critical problem that affects data integrity, or can it be safely ignored?

I notice about 5 of these errors scroll by during a backup of a database of approx 350GB in size.

It is encouraging that the process ends with a "completed OK!" message:

```
180722 04:28:01 Finished backing up non-InnoDB tables and files
180722 04:28:01 [01] Streaming aria_log.00000001 to <STDOUT>
180722 04:28:01 [01]        ...done
180722 04:28:01 [01] Streaming aria_log_control to <STDOUT>
180722 04:28:01 [01]        ...done
180722 04:28:01 [00] Streaming xtrabackup_binlog_info
180722 04:28:01 [00]        ...done
180722 04:28:01 Executing FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG ENGINE LOGS...
mariabackup: The latest check point (for incremental): '178257265448382'
180722 04:28:01 >> log scanned up to (178257268268307)
mariabackup: Stopping log copying thread
180722 04:28:01 >> log scanned up to (178257268268307)
180722 04:28:01 Executing UNLOCK TABLES
180722 04:28:01 All tables unlocked
180722 04:28:01 [00] Streaming ib_buffer_pool to <STDOUT>
180722 04:28:01 [00]        ...done
180722 04:28:01 Backup created in directory '/root/xtrabackup_backupfiles/'
MySQL binlog position: filename 'mysql-bin.006908', position '871204716', GTID of the last change '0-10-334787449'
180722 04:28:01 [00] Streaming backup-my.cnf
180722 04:28:01 [00]        ...done
180722 04:28:01 [00] Streaming xtrabackup_info
180722 04:28:01 [00]        ...done
mariabackup: Redo log (from LSN 178256909716559 to 178257268268307) was copied.
180722 04:28:01 completed OK!
```

I'm using the latest mariadb 10.3.8 and mariabackup 10.3.8 packages on Centos 7 (MariaDB server 10.3.8-MariaDB Linux (x86_64))